# Adjusting Font for Different Sections of Same Paragraph - Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am feeding data into a Word doc from Excel via VBA. I want to format like the 
following.

> *1.* ***Service Ticket# 452345:***  *Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
>   labore et dolore magna aliqua.*

The Service Ticket part bold and italicized and the description italicized only. The Service ticket number and description come from different cells in Excel.

Here's my code:

```
'' Bookmark where I will be inserting the data.
wdApp.Selection.GoTo what:=-1, Name:="Service_Ticket_Comments"

Dim i As Integer
Dim serviceTicket As String

For i = 4 To shAuditTrail.Range("A4").End(xlDown).Row


    '' Pulling comments from the comments column.
    If Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 11)) Then

          serviceTicket = "Service Ticket #" & Cells(i, 1)

          wdApp.Selection.TypeText "Service Ticket #" & Cells(i, 1)
          wdApp.Selection.Font.Bold = True
          wdApp.Selection.Font.Italic = True


          wdApp.Selection.TypeText " - " & Cells(i, 11) & Chr(10) & Chr(10)
          wdApp.Selection.Font.Italic = True
    End If

Next
```

This makes the Service Ticket part and description bold and italized because selection is applied to the whole piece. How do I only keep the first part bold and italicized and the other part just bold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't work with `Selection`, instead, work with `Range`, same as you would in Excel.

It's not clear where the Selection in the target Word document comes from, so I have no choice in using that as the starting point. But usually you'd only use this technique if the target is chosen by the user...

```
Dim rng as Word.Range
Set rng = wdApp.Selection.Range
rng.Text = serviceTicket
rng.Font.Bold = True
rng.Font.Italic = True
rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
rng.Text = Cells(i,11) & vbCr
rng.Font.Bold = False
rng.Font.Italic = True
```

**Note**: You should actually create / use *character styles* for this formatting, rather than applying the formatting directly. This results in more efficent code and a more manageable document.

Comment: Your code is lumping all the service tickets numbers first and followed by description.

Comment: My code is only to demonstrate how to use the Range object to insert something, format it, insert something else, and format it differently. You need to provide the logic for generating the service numbers and description - I simply pulled some of the information from your code in order to give mine some context to make it more understandable.

Answer (score 1):

You can format specific characters in a cell with the Range Characters property. (See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198232.aspx)
For example, the following routine will italicise and make bold all the text up to and including the the search string for each cell in the range. In the case, the string being sought is also passed as a parameter.

```
Sub TestMacro()
   Call BoldItalicsPartofCell(Selection, ":")
End Sub


Sub BoldItalicsPartofCell(rng As Range, searchstr)
   Dim singlecell As Range     'Loop counter
   Dim beforecolon As Integer  'Starting position of search string

   For Each singlecell In rng
      beforecolon = InStr(singlecell, searchstr) - 1 + Len(searchstr)
      If beforecolon > 0 Then
         With singlecell.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=beforecolon).Font
            .FontStyle = "Bold Italic"
            '.Underline = True  'If you want udnerlined as well!
         End With
      End If
   Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

use `InsertAfter` :

```
wdApp.Selection.TypeText "Service Ticket #" & Cells(i, 1)
wdApp.Selection.Font.Bold = True
wdApp.Selection.Font.Italic = True

wdApp.Selection.InsertAfter " - " & Cells(i, 11) & Chr(10) & Chr(10)
wdApp.Selection.Font.Bold = False
wdApp.Selection.Font.Italic = True
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not elegant but I made it work.

```
If Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 11)) Then

                With wdApp.Selection

                        .Paragraphs.Indent
                        .Font.Bold = True
                        .Font.Italic = True
                        .TypeText Chr(10) & Chr(10) & numList & ".  "


                        .Font.Underline = True
                        .TypeText "Service Ticket #" & Cells(i, 1) & ":"


                        .Font.Bold = False
                        .Font.Underline = False
                        .TypeText "  " & Cells(i, 11)
                        .Paragraphs.Reset
                End With

          numList = numList + 1

    End If
```